# R how to add linear trendline based on summary database

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, trendline

I am attempting to make a linear trendline based on a summary database with calculated means and standard errors.  The idea is I want to have 4 points each representing a high or low shelter module at two different study sites (Waikiki and Hanauma Bay).

#### Database

```
data <- structure(list(Site_long = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Hanauma Bay", 
"Waikiki"), class = "factor"), Shelter = c("High", "Low", "High", 
"Low"), mean_urchin = c(408.408115828422, 140.379098168879, 13.52445484726, 
4.94269044271269), mean_algae = c(0.823598077528884, 0.90810903848719, 
0.907753323551643, 0.89177862643068), standard_error_urchin = c(72.3961797019843, 
27.120064093754, 8.47543198370478, 2.29511348616285), standard_error_algae = c(0.0242715527026854, 
0.0109737470337568, 0.00941191528094468, 0.0122105898310865), 
    lower_urchin = c(336.011936126438, 113.259034075125, 5.04902286355523, 
    2.64757695654983), upper_urchin = c(480.804295530406, 167.499162262633, 
    21.9998868309648, 7.23780392887554), lower_algae = c(0.799326524826198, 
    0.897135291453433, 0.898341408270698, 0.879568036599593), 
    upper_algae = c(0.847869630231569, 0.919082785520947, 0.917165238832587, 
    0.903989216261766)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), groups = structure(list(
    Site_long = structure(1:2, .Label = c("Hanauma Bay", "Waikiki"
    ), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(1:2, 3:4), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = 1:2, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[image]

When I add a geom_smooth() to my plot code, it does not render a trendline at all.

#### Graph code

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = mean_urchin, y = mean_algae, fill = Shelter, shape = Site_long)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = 3)) +
  stat_smooth(method=lm) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(21, 24)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(NA, "black"), guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 21))) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower_algae, ymax = upper_algae), position = position_dodge(.8), width = .1) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = lower_urchin, xmax = upper_urchin), position = position_dodge(.8), width = .1) +
  
  labs(x = "Mean urchin biomass (Kg) ± SEM", y = "Mean benthic algal cover ± SEM")
```

[image]

Is it possible to render a trendline based on a summary database like this or do I have to link it to the raw database?  I attempted to use the raw data to generate the trendline but then ended up with 4 separate trendlines which is not what I want.

[image]

Any insight or advice would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: `stat_smooth(method=lm, aes(fill = NULL, shape = NULL))`

Comment: @Roland thanks!  This solved my issue.  If you want to post this as a solution I can mark it as solved